# How to copy text within a Table Cell then find and replace strings keeping formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing some VBA code in a MS Word document.

I have created a table in the document, it is multiple rows by 2 columns.

The first column contains a title such as "Welcome Letter" and the second column of the table contains the body of the message "Dear [Client], we welcome you to our company...."

I want to be able to create a button or some sort of form that will copy the contents of column2, replace the [client] with a variable that I might create i.e Dim clientname = 'Bob' and then put the message into the clipboard ready for pasting into an email.

The templates have rich text formatting too, so that would need to be maintained.  I've had a play but I'm unable to keep the rich text formatting, as soon as replace something the formatting is lost.

Anybody have any ideas of how this could be achieved? A colleague suggested that I should create a new word document in the background and use that for the replacements.  I'm stomped and all ears to your suggestions. Cheers !

Comment: I think your only hope of an answer is to ask on superuser.com, your question does not seem to be programming related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formfield for the name and simply access the text by using it's DOM object like this:

```
ThisDocument.Formfields("name of formfield").Result
```

From here you can save the text to a variable or replace the text at will. I think it will keep the formatting but if it doesn't then you can research using Content Controls to set a portion of your document as a rich text area. Here's the info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836891(v=office.15).aspx

I hope this helps.